# Get fields and their values at runtime using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

I am trying to get fields and their values of an object at runtime. Below is the code sample:

```
public static int calculateProfileStrenght(Object inputObj,
            Map<String, Integer> configMap) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException {

        int someValue= 0;
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : configMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key=" + entry.getKey() + ", Value="+ entry.getValue());
            try {
                Field field = inputObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                System.out.println("No such field: "+entry.getKey());
            } 
        }
        return someValue;

    }
```

As shown above, the Map contains key-value pairs, where the key is going to be the field name (or variable name) from `inputObj`. I need to read the value of this field from  `inputObj`. The datatype of the fields are String, int, Date, etc. 
`inputObj`

```
    public class UserDetails {


        private int userId;
        private String userName;
        private Date joinedDate;
        private Address homeAddress;
        private String description; 

        // getters and setters
}
```

I can't do field.getLong or getChar, etc since the method is generic and doesn't know about the datatypes of the fields of `inputObj`.

I need to read the field values in the for loop and apply the business logic. Is this even possible? I tried a lot of ways but to no luck. Any references/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed `field.get(Object)` method. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

how about this method in Filed ：Object  get(Object obj)
this method returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the specified object.

Answer (score -1):

`field.getType()` returns the type of the field (`int.class`, `Date.class`, etc). You can easily perform different actions depending on its return value.

```
Class<?> type = field.getType();
if(type == int.class) {
    // load an int
} else if(type == Date.class) {
    // load a Date
} else if(type == String.class) {
    // load a String
}
// etc
```